# Set homepage default route for application in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

In my application following is default route

```
       routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "WC.UI.Controllers" }
        );
```

Now I want that Home page should be some other view from some area so I added bellow route just above the default route

```
       routes.MapRoute(
            "MainPage",
            "",
            new {area = "Contest", controller = "Home", action = "Index"},
             namespaces: new[] { "WC.UI.Areas.Contest.Controllers" }
        );
```

So according to me by default calling "http://localhost:59616/" it should go to view which is inside Area "Contest", but what happens here is that it does goes to "Contest/Home/Index" action but renders Index.cshtml from outer view folder.

Answer (score 0):

try to give **url** parameter with complete Path of your area like,

**url: "AreaName/{controller}/{action}/{id}"**.